# Consecutive sibling selectors in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I'm using consecutive sibling selectors from a hidden field to hide elements:

```
input.nexthidden[type="hidden"] + fieldset,
input.nexthidden[type="hidden"] + fieldset.group-doc-upload + fieldset {
    display: none;
}

input.nexthidden[type="hidden"][value="showtrue"] + fieldset,
input.nexthidden[type="hidden"][value="showtrue"] + fieldset.group-doc-upload + fieldset {
    display: block;
}
```

In Firefox and Internet Explorer this works fine. In Chrome, the second set of selectors don't work (the first ones do). When I check the "computed" tab in element inspector, it shows `display: block` as the computed value.

Curiously, when I expand the property, it shows me how it came to reach this value and says:

`input.nexthidden[type="hidden"] + fieldset, input.nexthidden[type="hidden"] + fieldset.group-doc-upload + fieldset - none (style.css:916)`

<del>`fieldset - block`</del>`(User Agent Stylesheet)`

The user agent's `display: block` is clearly struck out and there are no other styles that affect the display property. Yet still `display: block` is computed.

Does Chrome not like consecutive `+` selectors?

Comment: Chrome does not like `+` selectors in general. Does changing one or all of them to `~` work?

Comment: You are correct, changing one of the consecutive selectors to a `~` made it work.

Comment: I just tested it and cannot reproduce the issue on Chrome/Win 40: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/2L6hxwzr What version and platform are you testing on?

Comment: I'm on Win / Chrome 39.0.2171.95. Strangely, your JS Fiddle worked for me. Perhaps there's something else on the page that's causing an issue.

Comment: You might want to add the HTML to your question in that case (and see if you can reproduce it in a fiddle of your own). Generally if a selector matches correctly on Firefox and IE, I would not expect the issue to be in the markup. But for all we know, something in it might be tripping up Chrome.

Comment: It's highly possible this proprietary system is generating invalid markup on the page. It's a bit weird that `a ~ b + c` works, while `a + b + c` works, especially seeing as IE isn't having trouble with it. I'll stick with using `~` for now, and check the page for validation errors. Thanks for the help.